# How to get view and scroll like make my trip application "Hot Deals" section.?

Tags: android

i followed this tutorial "https://github.com/DevExchanges/ViewPagerCards"
i got the view like hotdeals section of MMT.But now i also want to change the image while swiping of cardview same as MMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

you should be add two viewpager.

One for imagePager and second for cardviewPager

```
cardviewPager .addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            imagePager.setCurrentItem(position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Viewpagers you can change the image by using the listener of  onPageChanged.